# Add new listener to custom TextView

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

**how do i create a listener to this text view?**
I try to create custom text view but the hole program collapse when i register it to new listener.

this is the code of the extended class and the xml code. the row which the program collapse in is bolded.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{   

    class Layout
    {
        public Layout()
        {
            thisTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thisTextView);
        }
        TextView thisTextView;
    }

    class Events
    {
        public Events()
        {
            l.thisTextView.
            setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {   **// this is where the program collapse**
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    l.thisTextView.setText("Work!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    Layout l;
    Events e;
    Context ctx;

        public ChordCustumeTextView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);

            ctx = context;
            l = new Layout();
            e = new Events();
        }

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            l.thisTextView.setText("Work!");
        }
}
```

xml -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/thisTextView"
    android:clickable="true">
</TextView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the program collapse" ?

Comment: layoutinflater use to initialize `thisTextView`

Comment: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.chord_custume_text_view, null)` try this

Answer (score 0):

As per your given code, it is clearly visible that `Layout l` is `null` at the time you call `l.thisTextView.setText("Work!");`.

Therefore, you must need to initialize `l` before calling any methods on it.